# Giving indices to list entries

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list looking like this:

```
A1 = ['a','a','a','foo','c','d','a','e','bar','bar','bar','e','d','d']
```

I want to transform it into this...

```
A2 = [1,1,1,2,3,4,1,5,6,6,6,5,4,4]
```

...where entries in A1 are taken in order and given an incremental index in A2.

Is there a straight forward way to do this in Python?

Comment: To nitpick - this is a Python [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) rather than an [array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of doing it can be.

```
>>> A1 = ['a','a','a','foo','c','d','a','e','bar','bar','bar','e','d','d']
>>> ref = []
>>> for i in A1:
...    if i not in ref:
...        ref.append(i)
... 
>>> [ref.index(i)+1 for i in A1]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
```

*Logic*

We remove the duplicate values in the original list (whilst preserving order). Then we find the index of the individual items in the list with respect to the original list.

*Advantages*

- Simple concepts/ Beginner level
- Very much straight forward.

*Disadvantages*

- Slow as it is of the order O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Although this solution gives the correct answer, it is potentially slow for large lists. You are iterating twice over `A1`, and both `i not in ref` and `ref.index(i)` do a linear scan over `ref`, so this has worst case `O(n^2)` performance when all items in `A1` are unique. The solution by YXD is much cleaner, and has `O(n)` performance.

Comment: @Bas I have edited. Do mention if I have to add any other disclaimers to display that my answer is very bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

```
index_map = {}
result = []

i = 0 # or 1 or whatever

for value in A1:
    if value not in index_map:
        index_map[value] = i
        i = i + 1
    result.append(index_map[value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to create a dictionary that produces unique ids on demand for each new key:

```
>>> unique_ids = collections.defaultdict(itertools.count(start=1).next)
>>> [unique_ids[item] for item in A1]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though similar to Bhargav Rao's answer, this may be faster for longer arrays (especially with high numbers of unique elements) given its use of hashing.

```
A1 = ['a','a','a','foo','c','d','a','e','bar','bar','bar','e','d','d']
uniqueEntries = 0
ref = {}
A2 = []
for x in A1:
    if x not in ref:
        uniqueEntries += 1
        ref[x] = uniqueEntries
    A2.append(ref[x])
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment on @BhargavRao's answer.

Comment: I would have, but I cannot yet comment on another person's response.

Answer (score -1):

This could hurt your eyes but it works, just use `sets`:

`[list(set(your_list)).index(x) for x in your_list]`

Comment: This does not work exactly as requested, since the order of `list(set(...))` is somewhat random, since sets are unordered. The question was to get the index in order of first appearance.

Comment: @BasSwinckels the same order is keeped here